# I want to select specific columns specified by user in Spring boot JPA and Angular 7

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, angular7

I have a project in spring boot and angular 7.
Data is displayed in tabular format.
To display all data **findAll()** method of JPA is good but now the problem is I want to use MyView + filter by which the user can select which columns to be displayed. Also, filters should be applied only to visible columns.
This is my main entitiy

```
    @Entity
    @Table("user")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name", length = 2000)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="imei", length = 20)
    private String imei;

    @Column(name="address", length = 10)
    private String address;

    @Column(name="pincode", length = 10)
    private String pincode;
    
    @Column(name="latitude", length = 20)
    private String latitude;
    
    @Column(name="longitude", length = 20)
    private String longitude;
    
    @Column(name="contact_no", length = 10)
    private String contactNo;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id", nullable = false)
    private Country country;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="state_id", nullable = false)
    private State state;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id", nullable = false)
    private City city;

    @Column(name="is_active", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 1", insertable = false)
    private Boolean isActive;
    
    @Column(name="created_on")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
    
    public User() {
        
    }
}
```

This is MyView entity

```
@Entity
@Table("my_view")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyView {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty( access = Access.WRITE_ONLY )
    private User user;  
    
    @Column(name="column_name", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String columnName;
    
    @Column(name="visible", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 1", insertable = false)
    private Boolean visible;
    
    public MyView() {
        
    }
}
```

Now, suppose I get 
first_name, last_name, pincode, imei and contact_no from myview table and filter's are applied from UI like **pincode starting with 4220%** and **last_name is 'furry'.**  
then how can I create query in JPA.
**Note: Column selection will change for each user and accordingly filters will also change.**

Comment: you can build dynamically query for this. See https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications and https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic filters you can use [Query By Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) in simple cases or [`Specifications`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) in more advanced cases.

Limiting the columns selected is normally done in Spring Data JPA by using a [projection interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) as return value.
But doing that dynamically is not possible and either way you can't combine it with the options for dynamic where clauses.

Therefore the solution is to [implement a custom method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), get an `EntityManager` injected, construct your query as required using the Criteria API or String concatenation of a JPQL statement (not recommended due to the risk of SQL injection).